# how to find a key of array in smarty

Tags: arrays, key, smarty

hii to all..i am new to smarty..and i didnt look depth in smarty..i had an array.how can i get a particular key value as a string in smarty..

thx in advance.

Answer (score 6):

If you already have an existing array assigned via smarty, then you can access keys and values using the smarty foreach loop.

```
{foreach from=$array key="key" item="value"}
{$key} => {$value}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$country=array('INDIA','United State');
$smarty->assign('country',$country);

Then you can use like
{$country[0]}
{$country[1]}


$country=array('IND'=>INDIA','US'=>'United State');
$smarty->assign('country',$country);

Then you can use Something Like This
{$country.IND}
{$country.US}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$myarray['mykey'] = 'myvalue';
$smarty->assign('myarray', $myarray);

The value is: <strong>{$myarray.mykey}</strong>
```

I'd say that you can find all this and more just looking at the documentation.